# GWT RPC Data Encryption and gwt-crypto issue

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, encryption

I have a GWT app, which is deployed on the app engine. The application is basically an exam simulator. All the exam questions and answers are stored in an XML file on the server. I use JAXB parser to parse the XML file and send a list of objects to the client through GWT RPC.

I noticed that during the transit (server -> client), the entire data is visible in plain text in Firebug. Since the data (exam questions and answers) are my intellectual property (IP) and something that I give lot of value to, I'm concerned that it's very easy to steal that data. Therefore, I'm trying to find ways to do some basic encryption and obfuscate the content when it's being sent over from the server to the client.

After Googling, I came across gwt-crypto project, and within a few minutes, I was able to achieve the exact result that I wanted. The server would encrypt the data, and the client would decrypt it. In Firebug, it would show the data in encrypted format, and not as plain text.

However, I ran into an issue. After implementing encryption/decryption, I noticed that my application would not load inside my company's network, which is obviously protected by a firewall. The application works perfectly from home or even on a 3G network on my phone. Another version of the application, which does not use encryption/decryption works perfectly from within my company's network. I confirmed this by creating 2 exact same versions of the app, with the only difference between a boolean flag, that determines whether encryption/decryption is enabled or disabled.

I have the following questions here:

1. What is the best way to achieve the result that I want to achieve? Is gwt-crypto a good solution for that? I'm fine with any simple approach to obfuscate the data during transit. It doesn't have to be a sophisticated algorithm.
2. What could be the possible reason for a GWT app, with encryption/decryption enabled, not working inside a firewall? I'm really clueless on this.

I'll appreciate any help on this issue.

Comment: Just so we are clear, you understand that the user can just take screen shots to capture your intellectual property. Where are you trying to protect the data? Just in transit, or even when it gets to the client's browser?

Comment: GregS - I perfectly understand that. I just want to make things difficult for an average user. I'm trying to protect it in transit only. They can certainly go to the extent of taking screenshots or retyping the content all over again, or viewing the source and copy-pasting it out. I just don't like the idea of exposing a huge part of the content in plain text through Firebug or other such tools. So, this is NOT a matter of making a 100% secure system. If you have a better solution, I'm willing to give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: For transit, you would use SSL rather than trying to roll your own with GWT-crypto.

Comment: You are right. But GAE doesn't support SSL for custom domains (AFAIK) and I do not want to use myappid.appspot.com domain for my application. Thanks.

Comment: You're diving down a rabbit-hole here. Nothing you can do is going to make it impossible for users to extract your data, and nothing you're likely to implement is likely to make it even slightly difficult. For instance, I can use Firebug or the Chrome dev tools to view the computed DOM and extract the text after your code has decrypted it. I think you're overestimating how valuable 'your' data is to other people, and who your potential adversaries are.

Comment: Nick - I appreciate your comments. It's likes putting an ordinary door lock on your house versus leaving the door completely open. A determined thief will get in either way, but at least that ordinary lock will not invite everyone to have a look inside. I do have reasons to overestimate the value of the data, as well as being paranoid about it, because of some past experiences. So, while I do not want to go too far, I do want to add a layer of obscurity and leave it at that. GWT-crypto seemed to meet the bill perfectly, but I can't get it to work behind a firewall. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using SSL is the right way to go.

In your case, given AppEngine SSL limitations, you should load your HTML normally from non-SSL domain and use [cross-site RPC](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/Xsite.html) to load your data via SSL domain.

**Update:**

```
What is the best way to achieve the result that I want to achieve?
```

If you want to secure the data in transit then the only secure option is SSL/HTTP. Usually it's also the simplest one as it does not require you to change the application code, just server configuration. In your particular case (appengine with private domain), it takes more work as described above.

```
 Is gwt-crypto a good solution for that?
```

No. `gwt-crypto` uses a key to encrpt/decrypt the data. You also need a secure way to discribute this key.

```
I'm fine with any simple approach to obfuscate the data during transit.
```

[Security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) in not security. It's a false sense of security, which is even more dangerous than no security. It's enough that only one of the technically capable students cracks this and soon everybody would do it.

Possible attack would go like this:

1. Snoop the network, get username/password of user.
2. Login as that user, have browser load exam data, which is now unencrypted in memory.
3. [Dump the DOM](http://www.lemoda.net/javascript/dump-dom/dump-dom.html) and inspect it for exam questions.

-

```
What could be the possible reason for a GWT app, with encryption/decryption
enabled, not working inside a firewall?
```

Use firebug to make sure network connections are identical, except for the encrypted content. Firewalls should not work that deep. Talk to sysadmin about it.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. I went through that link, but I'm having a hard time trying to relate it to my requirement as well as your suggestion. I admit that I'm not knowledgeable enough to understand it. So could you elaborate more on how to go about doing it? I just want to obfuscate the content and not really concerned about making it very secure, at this point. A simple solution, like gwt-crypto, would meet my requirement very well.

Comment: Peter, your update is definitely useful. SSL for custom domains is on GAE roadmap, and is overdue now. I'm waiting for them to provide it out of the box. I'm willing to accept the risk and go with obscurity (rather than real security) at this point because the data that I'm releasing now is a subset of the entire set, which will follow in a few months. I'm not disputing anything you said, and agree that SSL is the way to go. I'll try to talk to the sysadmin. In the meanwhile, do you know of any alternatives? I cannot go live with all the data visible in plain text to everyone. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to do some testing by enabling SSL on one of my test applications deployed on GAE. I noticed that on the client side, I could still see the content that came over from the server in plain text in Firebug. Is that how it is supposed to work, or did I missing something in my testing?

Comment: Yes, firebug is "inside" browser. It sees the communication after it comes off the HTTPS.

Comment: That's how I interpreted it as well. Thanks for confirming this. So, SSL is "not" going to solve my problem. Using gwt-crypto for encryption, at least when I see the data received from the RPC call from the server, it shows encrypted information. The client does the decryption and shows the questions on the UI. Obviously, that doesn't make it secure in any way, but at least it does add one extra layer of obscurity. Peter - thanks a lot for patiently answering each of my questions and guiding me in the right direction.